# Circular reference exception in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interceptor

I have the following factory definition in my angularjs spa:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('snApp')
  .factory('Auth', ['$http', 'localStorageService', function ($http,     localStorageService) {

   //code goes here
  }]);
})();
```

and then in my config for my app, i have the following http interceptor setup:

```
var app = angular.module('snApp', ['ui.router', 'LocalStorageModule', ])
.config(['$logProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider',     '$provide', function ($logProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider,     $provide) {

    // Intercept http calls.
  $provide.factory('RequestHttpInterceptor', function ($q, Auth) {
      return {
          // On request success
          request: function ($config) {
              if (Auth.user) {
                  $config.headers['XToken'] = Auth.user.token;
              }
              return $config;
          }
      };
  });
  // Add the interceptor to the $httpProvider.
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('RequestHttpInterceptor');
}]);
```

When I run the app, I get the following error:

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep]`

I think it has something to do with the $http in my Auth, because if I remove that then it works, but I need it!

If someone can help me understand what im doing wrong, that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I figured it out. Since its a http interceptor, angular doesn't like the fact that you are passing in $http to your factory - which makes sense, because if you call $http in an http interceptor it will invoke the interceptor, which will invoke the $http, etc etc getting this infinite loop.

Luckily I just needed a property in the factory so i abstracted that out of the Auth factory so that $http wasnt needed. There are other ways to do it, but this was the best solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can still inject the `$injector` and create the `$http` when required.  See [here](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/) for some examples.

Another option is to emit/broadcast a message and capture this elsewhere (for example, as part of a run.)